# How to store a private message in NEAR?

Tags: nearprotocol

Are there any built-in mechanisms in NEAR for storing private messages, or does the contract need its own code for encrypting message contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does the contract need its own code for encrypting message contents?

Contract shouldn't be encrypting/decrypting messages, as everything executed on blockchain layer is visible to everyone.

However you can store already encrypted messages and do encryption/decryption client-side (i.e. in JS). Most convenient way to do this is use the same crypto library as used in nearlib:

https://tweetnacl.js.org/

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in way and right now contract has to handle encryption on their own. I think there will be more crypto function bindings introduced to runtime such as encryption, signature, etc in the future.